# Access Search Form Challenge Using Unbound Text Boxes To Return Min To Max Range Or Specific Criteria

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm trying to use unbound text boxes for users to search for products designed to fit either a specific edge thickness, or products designed to fit a min to max range of edge thicknesses.

Users that want a product designed to fit a range of edge thicknesses cannot use a product that only handles a single specific edge thickness.

Users that want a product designed to fit a specific edge thickness can use a product that handles a range of edge thicknesses, as long as the edge thickness they enter is within that product's range.

I've created a demo database. Access file downloadable here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4lLf1PWvL_Tc09YYjBLaDlET3c

If a user enters a value into the specific edge thickness section, the min and max text boxes become invisible.

Can someone please assist me with this query design?

Answer (score 1):

You have all your criteria on one line.  Move the 'FITS SPECIFIC EDGE THICKNESS' down a line so you have a 'or' criteria.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Comment: Ankit, I am sorry I didn't see any previous answer to this question.  Looking now, I still don't.  I will try to speed up my learning curve.  Please clarify where I would look to see a previous answer to this question.

Comment: @ankitsuthar: If you think this is a duplicate of another question, feel free to flag it; otherwise, there is certainly no point in chiding others for not having found the very same questions you *also* haven't found.

Comment: Ok First Please explain your answer with little more detail regarding the question.  Second, You can link any reference if you have. or some suitable example would be great if has.  And for my first comment is the quick response from my side where I review your answer so at that time it didn't show the all answers so you have to react to that situation.  I know you are currently not eligible for comment but please make sure that the given first and second suggestion will be followed while answering on SO. Thanks